# javascript class killing app

Tags: javascript, function

just a quick one, im using a oop style for my javascript game but for some reason when i add in a new class it kills any functions from other classes i have included.

Here is the script i am talking about which is my main file which i will include all my class files in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var canvas = document.getElementById("TBG");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var ui = new Gui();
// var level = new Level();

//----------Login/Register Gui --------------
$('#TBG').hide();
$('#load-new').hide();
$('#reg').hide();
$('#login').hide();

//if login_but is clicked do ui.login function
$('#login_but').click(ui.login);
//if reg_but is clicked do ui.register function
$('#reg_but').click(ui.register);

$('#new_but').click(function(){
    game_settings("new");
});

$('#load_but').click(function(){
    game_settings("load");
});

//if login_sumbit button is clicked do ui.login_ajax function
$("#login_submit").click(ui.login_ajax);

$("#reg_submit").click(ui.register_ajax);

$("#welcome").on("click", "#logout_but", ui.logout);


  //___________________________________________________________________

//Initialisation of game

function game_settings(state){
    if(state == "load"){
        ui.load_game();
        //do ajax call to load user last save
        level.level_init(0,1);
    }
    else{
        //set beginning params


        //Change screens
        ui.new_game();
        alert("new game");
    }
}

});
```

in the context of the script above, my problem is when i just have the call to new Gui() without the call to new level underneath or commented like you can see, well then all of the functions below under the heading login/register gui works perfectly, but as soon as i put the call to new level in or uncomment it, it kills all of the functions under the login/ register gui  heading.

Why is this?

**EDIT**: here is the level.js file in case you would like to see it and how i am constructing my classes:

```
function Level(){

this.level_init = function(level, location){

    var saved_level = level;
    var saved_location = location;

};


this.get_tileset = function(){

};

this.draw = function() {

}
   }
```

Thanks

Tom

Comment: It sounds like your `Level` function has a bug.

Comment: Its not strictly OOP, just the use of classes to contain each part of my game. e.g. level_loader, player, collision etc

Comment: @ruakh, i will edit to include my level function, i cant see how it would cause the js to bug out

Comment: @TomBurman: If your function throws an exception, then obviously, after you call it, nothing else will be run.

Comment: @TomBurman wrap `var level = new Level();` with `try..catch` so you can catch your error

Comment: Are you sure you're including your `level.js`? If not, then `Level` will be undefined, and `new Level()` will fail.

Comment: @TomBurman is there any errors in browser console?

Comment: @ruakh, i believe i am, i have used the same technique as i did with new Gui, which works fine when i dont have the call to the level class underneath it

Comment: @ant_Ti nope im using firebug and i recieve no erros at all, and i also just tried a try catch wrapped around my level class but had no response because the file cant actuall call level

Comment: I have just retested jsut the include and firebug has came back with the error,

Comment: ReferenceError: Level is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

var level = new Level(); ...... but i dont see why? as gui works fine

Comment: @TomBurman check network tab. Is there any error with loading level.js?

Answer (score 0):

SOrry guys, it turns out it was a silly mistake on my behalf i didnt add the script in html!, i need more sleep i think haha! thanks for your input

TOm